# Code involves WhenEvent and DiscreteVariables no longer works

Tags: differential-equations, bugs, event-detection, discrete

**Bug introduced after 10.0, in or before 10.3, persisting through 13.2.1**

---

The exact problem I am dealing with has already been asked and answered [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/47141/how-to-change-a-parameter-dynamically-inside-ndsolve?newreg=d64ac7916678455da488bb7490957b43).

Unfortunately the solution no longer seems to work. In fact when I run the solution

```
equation = x'[t] + (x[t] - λ[t]) == 0;

sol = NDSolveValue[{equation, x[0] == 0, λ[0] == 1, 
                    WhenEvent[x'[t] == 0.25, λ[t] -> x[t]]}, 
                   x, {t, 0, 5}, DiscreteVariables -> {λ}]
```

I get nothing back. There is no error indication. *Mathematica* simply stops after a single integration step and returns nothing. I have already checked that the solution works fine if I simply replace in the condition inside `WhenEvent` with `x[t] == 0.25` instead of the first derivative.

My speculation is that at some point someone decided to remove the possibility of using a WhenEvent with a condition that depends on a discrete variable when the action affects the discrete variable itself. Is there some workaround to this? It is unavoidable that my condition must have `x'[t]` in it.

Answer (score 1):

The code works fine in *v9.0.1*, but behaves as OP describes at least since *v12.3.1*. I believe this is a bug related to pre-processing, because

```
equation = x'[t] + (x[t] - λ[t]) == 0;
sol = NDSolveValue[{equation, x[0] == 0, λ[0] == 1, 
   WhenEvent[x'[t] == 0.25, λ[t] -> x[t]]}, x, {t, 0, 5}, 
  DiscreteVariables -> {λ}, SolveDelayed -> True]
```

fixes the problem. (`SolveDelayed` is red, but don't worry. If you don't like it, use the equivalent `Method -> {EquationSimplification -> Residual}` instead. )

Comment: Thanks for the proposal! I will give that a shot. I think the method "Residual" doesn't use Parallelization automatically right? I am generally using "ExplicitRungeKutta" because that makes the calculation 8-fold faster. The example above was just a toy example, In reality I am evolving thousands of coupled equations each of which has thousands of terms.  Any tips for doing this calculation faster? I tried replacing the derivative using the eoms and that also seems to work but at a cost of speed.

Comment: @pip AFAIK parallelization is not that relevant here. Currently the ODE solver of `NDSolve` doesn't parallelize, either. What's parallelized is the basic arithmetic operation when the system is large. See discussion in https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/208784/1871 Also, generally the `ExplicitRungeKutta` method isn't that efficient according to my (limited) experience, but who knows. For large system, compilation is often a good choice, but that's relatively advanced topic, see e.g. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/208762/1871